# TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined. Discord bot Dashboard EJS issue

Tags: node.js, discord.js, typeerror, ejs

When I was busy coding on my Dashboard on my bot, I got this error for the dashboard link. The programming language was JS which was supposed to be compiled to EJS.

This is the code:

```js
app.get("/dashboard", checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    const server = client.guilds.cache.get("903769597986103399");
    let user = server.members.cache.has(req.user.id);
});
```

This is the error: (from discord.js, I used Replit)

````
TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
    at /home/runner/Kokili/dashboard/dashboard.js:640:25
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at checkAuth (/home/runner/Kokili/dashboard/dashboard.js:138:41)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:91:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:110:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/runner/Kokili/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12) ```
````

Comment: `server` is undefined. Probably the Guild with the ID `903769597986103399` is not in the cache. Try to fetch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Caching

As pointed out by [@Jakye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10012735/jakye), likely the guild you are trying to access has not been added to the cache. In order to resolve this, fetch the guild using `<Guild>.fetch()` then get the members. This would look something like this:

```js
const server = client.guilds.cache.fetch("903769597986103399");
```

Comment: I am not really working on the project anymore but working on a new one but thanks for helping me.